# How i replace java multiple chars and strings with others;

Tags: android, string, str-replace

I have a string from http request and i want to replace  multiple chars and strings with others.How i can do this?With Array for more efficient way?

```
      String result =" "hourly": [ {"cloudcover": "0", "humidity": "93", "precipMM": "0.0", "pressure": "1013", "sigHeight_m": "0.7", "swellDir": "70", "swellHeight_m": "0.5", "swellPeriod_secs": "1.0", "tempC": "9", "tempF": "48", "time": "0", "v";
      String result2 = result.replace("{", " ");
      String result3 = result2.replace("}", " ");
      String result4 = result3.replace("[", " ");
      String result5 = result4.replace("]", " ");
      String result6 = result5.replace("\"", "");

      String result7 = result6.replaceAll("......", "         ");
      String result8 = result7.replaceAll("cloudcover", "\n      \ncloudcover");
      String result9 = result8.replaceAll("winddir:", "    \nwinddir:");
      String result10 = result9.replaceAll("tempC:", "    \ntempC:");

    WeatherInfos.setText( result10 );//Shows the weather info
```

Comment: i think resoponse in json so no need to replace just using json..and then replace string if it is requried

Comment: You can use a `regex`!

Comment: is that a JSON response you are trying to operate on? post the http link that you are trying to parse. 
if its a JSON, why don't you parse the JSON object/array?

Comment: Ok.Tell me a tutorial or example with JSON array replace strings...

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
String result = "{\"hourly\": [ {\"cloudcover\": \"15\", \"humidity\": \"93\", \"pressure\": \"1013\", \"tempC\": \"9\", \"winddir\": \"25\"}]}";

if(!result.startsWith("{"))
    result = "{" + result + "}";

JSONObject JSONResult = new JSONObject(result);
JSONResult = (JSONObject) JSONResult.getJSONArray("hourly").get(0);

String cloudcover =  JSONResult.getString("cloudcover");
String tempC=  JSONResult.getString("tempC");
String winddir=  JSONResult.getString("winddir"); //i do not see winddir in your result

Toast.makeText(getapplicationContext(), "Cloud Cover is "+ cloudcover , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

now print cloudcover, winddir and tempC where ever you want.

Comment: How i get the info for example after winddir: 25?

Comment: for example "tempC: 19" i want to convert it to Temperature is 19 C

Comment: "hourly": [ {"cloudcover": "0", "humidity": "93", "precipMM": "0.0", "pressure": "1013", "sigHeight_m": "0.7", "swellDir": "70", "swellHeight_m": "0.5", "swellPeriod_secs": "1.0", "tempC": "9", "tempF": "48", "time": "0", "v

Comment: In JSON you directly get the value of the String that you are looking for e.g  JSONResult.getString("cloudcover"); will return value "0" of the cloudcover. 
So you don't need to run replace strings.
you just get the value for what you want

Comment: use the result string from my edited code and try again.
we need to use \" if we want to use " in our initialised strings.